# Eagle Cad: change default drill size list

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, via, through-hole

Eagle Cad specifies certain drill and hole sizes, for example, used for VIAs, when routing.

I know that I can enter the drill size in the combo box and it will be remembered. But all the other "incorrect" default sizes remain there as well, as tempting as they are.
I also know how to specify a minimum drill size in DRC settings.

The question: how to replace the Eagle list of drill sizes (for vias) with my custom list, as per PCB manufacturing house specs? 
Do I really need to go into eagle configuration files, or there is another way, for example, using scripts?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done from the menu, although not very efficiently.

- Menu -> Options -> Set... -> Drill

where the user can delete or edit the default sizes one by one and add new ones.

Unfortunately there is not a way to save or load a preset configuration, like one can do with the DRC rules.

Comment: Hmmm, I also saw this, however, it has no effect for me. The settings done there are still there when I close / open the menu, but the added / modified values do not appear in the combo box when placing vias/holes...

Comment: There also appears to be a limit of 18 drill sizes there.